# On assumptions and calculation of O'Brien's "Global Statistical Test" for Multiple Endpoints Analysis

Tags: nonparametric, multiple-comparisons, dimensionality-reduction

As I understand, O'Brien's Global Statistical Test (GST) (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6534410/) for Multiple Endpoints Analysis is a method for mapping a multivariate problem on a univariate scale. The most common form of GST is the non-parametric form, based on rank sums. Final row of the figure below. (from https://www.quanticate.com/blog/global-statistical-test-for-multiple-endpoints-analysis)

[image: figure 1]

So my **first question** is, and I may be completely oversimplifying the matter and completely wrong, is non-parametric GST score basically the sum of ranks of each outcome? That's it?

My **second question** is: GST assumes all treatment effect sizes are the same across endpoints. How can this assumption possibly hold true in clinical trials? For example, how can we be sure a sample treatment has similar effects on all outcomes?

My **third question** is: how does this assumption hold when we intend to produce a composite outcome as a method of dimensional reduction? Generally, what are the pro and cons of using this method as a dimensional reduction method?

Please forgive any obvious mistake; disregarding the articles that applied the method, I couldn't find sufficient clear explanations on this subject.

Comment: Composite measures of multivariate endpoints are fraught with problems. A composite may be reasonable if each outcome is of equal clinical importance, but this rarely occurs. If the effect of treatment on each component of the composite is of interest, we can only hope that the authors provide the individual tests of effect. However, such reporting erodes at the initial choice of a composite measure.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't intend to use this method, rather I want to objectively criticize its application in my field of research, so I would much appreciate if anyone can answer my 3 questions so I have a better understanding of it. Especially on assumptions and specific advantages and disadvantages on my third question.